# Retrieving a piece of data from a different Active Record Model/table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Is it possible to retrieve the email address used by a user, posting a comment, in a list#show/show.html.erb view? Without adding another column "email" to my Comments model?

The best I can do is retrieve the user_id, which is not that helpful.

```
<% @list.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p><%= comment.body%></p>
  <p><%= comment.user_id %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list, optional: true
  belongs_to :user
```

Comments Table

```
  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "body"
    t.bigint "list_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["list_id"], name: "index_comments_on_list_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"
  end
```

List controller#show

```
    def show
        @list = List.find(params[:id])
        @current_user = current_user.id
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Module#delegate](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) from ActiveSupport:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list, optional: true
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :email, to: :user
end
```

---

```
<% @list.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p><%= comment.body%></p>
  <p><%= comment.user_id %> 
  <p><%= comment.email %>
<% end %>
```

And make sure you use `.includes` or `.eager_load` in the controller to avoid a N+1 query:

```
def show
  @list = List.includes(comments: :user).find(params[:id])
  @current_user = current_user.id
end
```

Comment: thank you for not only answering the question but aiding my learning by supplying the ActiveSupport guide/ref, I will read through it! The N+1 guidance is amazing. I hope you have an amazing day.